# How to add Quick Look support for OpenDocument file formats?

Tags: quicklook, open-source

I prefer OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice to MS Office because MS Office is expensive.

But OS X Quick View functionality that allows a preview of a file by taping space bar doesn't show an OpenDocument file's contents but just an icon.

- How can I add Quick Look support for OpenOffice files, like .ods, .odt and .odp ?

I know OpenOffice can write MS Office documents but it would be nice to have Quick Look understand the OpenDocument formats.

Note: ods are spreadsheets, odt are word processor documents and odp are presentations.

Comment: This would especially be useful for OpenOffice/LibreOffice since those apps are so slow to open. Not having to open them at all would be quite handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a longstanding request for it at
https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=68600

And an early implementation is at http://eric.bachard.free.fr/mac/aquavcl/patches/aqua_February2008/quicklook/

To install, place `OOoQuickLook.qlgenerator` from that site into `/Library/QuickLook` and wait a few minutes for QuickLook to detect the new generator.

Comment: Does anyone know the current status? Is there a more up-to-date QuickLook plugin for OpenOffice/`ods` files?

Comment: @Winterflags LibreOffice has its own enhancement request at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35361, but no progress from either camp.

Comment: This works with some limitations (until Mojave and with a low resolution). web.archive.org is your friend if you want to find the archive

Comment: Appears to be a dead link.

Answer (score 1):

[NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/) claims to offer [QuickLook support](http://neowiki.neooffice.org/index.php/NeoPeek). This may provide the functionality you are looking for.

Consider making a request for QuickLook support as part of OpenOffice; the [community pages](http://www.openoffice.org/support/index.html#community-support) are a good place to make this request more likely to be seen by the developers.